# OpenIdDict Multiple authorization servers can't decode the same access token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I'm working with a client that has a very strange network setup. Basically, they have multiple small segmented networks with their own clusters of servers because of several acquisitions, mergers, etc. It's a nightmare.

I've setup the authorization servers correctly and they're all running the same code but when I try to take my laptop from location to the other, I get logged out and have to log back in again. A lot of the employees travel between sites so getting logged out all the time is causing some grumbles.

The each instance of the APIs and Authorization servers are able to use the same database, but each site has it's own Authorization and Resource server.

What I've noticed is this:

- If I stay in one place, my access/refresh token setup works great with no problems
- If a travel to another site, the new sites authority server doesn't seem to be able to validate the access token and logs me out
- There is one site with a load balancer that will log me out randomly as well as if I'm traveling between sites.

The app is built on .NET Core 2.2 and OpenIDDict 2.0. For budgetary reasons, upgrading either is not an option.

Is there anyway to configure a shared certificate or key so that all of the servers can decode the access tokens? Basically multiple authorization servers able to decode the access tokens generated by any of the other authorization servers?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I had to change this:

```
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<DbContext>();
```

to this:

```
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("appName")
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate(MyX509Certificate2)
            .PersistKeysToDbContext<DbContext>();
```